# Javascript alert() not showing without const string?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

All I am trying to do is pop a javascript alert when a bool 'result' is false.

When 'result' is true, the javascript alert pops up successfully. However, when it is false, the alert does not show at all.

The only differences in the usage of each alert is that the unsuccessful alert uses a string variable while the successful alert uses a CONST string.

Is there a rule about javascript alert that only allows const string for the alert message?

Here is my code:

```
var sql = new SqlClass();
var result = sql.DataInsert(Label1.Text);
if (result == false)
{
    cancelButton_Click(this, e);
    string msg = LotInfo.SubmitError; //this is just a static string
    string script = string.Format("alert('{0}');", msg);
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, typeof(string), "Error", script, true);
}
else
{
    cancelButton_Click(this, e);
    const string msg = "Data successfully submitted!";
    string script = string.Format("alert('{0}');", msg);
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, typeof(string), "Success", script, true);
}
```

I'd like to add that LotInfo.SubmitError does hold a string that contains a SqlException message. When I store that string into a Label.Text, that label does show on my page.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:** The actual value of LotInfo.SubmitError is a SQL Error Message, so it really depends on what error I get.

Comment: It might be that `LotInfo.SubmitError`has quotation marks in it that will terminate the string and make the generated javascript incorrect.

Comment: Try `ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, typeof(string), "InsertError", script, true);` instead. There is already a JavaScript object called `Error` which may be conflicting with your script

Comment: Can you show us the actual value of `LotInfo.SubmitError`? Does it contain any apostrophes?

Comment: Also as a style comment: You should try to write your code with less duplicate lines...

Comment: @amura.cxg tried that, and it was still the same issue

Comment: @JLRishe it probably does, therefore, the error message is probably what's creating the issue. I'll let you know if that's the case.

Comment: @mortb that's probably the issue. LotInfo.SubmitError is holding a SQL error message so that's probably what's causing the issue.

Comment: `string script = string.Format("alert('{0}');", msg.Replace("'", "\'");` try that

Comment: @HugoYates thank you but that didn't resolve the issue. The quotation marks, other punctuation, etc. are definitely causing the issue tho.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up changing the string stored in LotInfo.SubmitError.

Instead of storing the SqlException.Message, I just stored a SqlException.Number along with a general message. I believe, as mortb and JLRishe suggested, the quotation marks, punctuation, etc stored in the SqlException.Message were terminating my javascript alert. Once, I changed the string to a message that didn't contain any punctuation, the alert popped up.

Thanks for everyone's help.

EDIT: Hugo Yates answer is also a solution but I didn't really want to reformat SQL Error Messages.

Answer (score 1):

Use `regex` to strip out any non-alphanumeric:

```
Regex r = new Regex("[^a-zA-Z0-9 -]"); //can be adjusted if required
string msg = LotInfo.SubmitError;
string script = string.Format("alert('{0}');",  r.Replace(msg, ""));
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, typeof(string), "Error", script, true);
```

If you want to tweak the regex condition have a look at this site http://www.regexr.com/ which is great for working out what the regex statement is doing.